# Scrollable content inside nested containers

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create scrollable content inside the below flex container like this...

[image: this picture]

...so the height of scrollable-content should be: left-screen-container - header - footer.

It would be important that the CSS of the *left-screen-container did not change* and that the scrollable-content always uses the remaining available space in screen-specific-content (until it needs to be scrollable).

The borders are only for visual representation.

Currently, the scrollable-content always increases its size and a body scrollbar appears. Any clever ideas?

```css
.left-screen-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.screen-specific-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.scrollable-content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  padding: 7px 12px 7px 12px;
  background-color: green;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-screen-container">
  <div class="screen-specific-content">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="scrollable-content">
      <!-- arbitrary list that would extend beyond the area of the left-screen-container -->
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There has to be a defined height somewhere along the line for overflow work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For an overflow setting to create the desired effect, the block-level element must have either a set height (height or max-height) or white-space set to nowrap. [mdn
> webdocs: Overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#description)

Flex-box

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.left-screen-container {
  height: 100vh;
}

.screen-specific-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.scrollable-content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  background-color: green;
}

.footer {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-screen-container">
  <div class="screen-specific-content">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="scrollable-content">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas congue lorem pellentesque scelerisque finibus. Quisque tristique a sem tincidunt malesuada. Nulla vitae nulla ligula. In scelerisque velit in magna congue, semper fermentum neque aliquam.
        Sed sit amet erat vel lacus lacinia elementum. Pellentesque elementum sit amet turpis ut tristique. Proin laoreet elit porta, maximus lorem a, eleifend nisi. Phasellus ut maximus est, a ornare eros. Mauris tellus velit, iaculis tincidunt arcu
        quis, porta vulputate augue. Duis mattis, ante eu vehicula auctor, est lectus hendrerit augue, vel sollicitudin nisl odio quis libero. Quisque dui tortor, sodales sollicitudin semper vitae, hendrerit nec sem. Donec aliquet auctor felis, vel dictum
        ligula bibendum rutrum. In varius lacinia leo, ut tempor mi ornare vitae.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas congue lorem pellentesque scelerisque finibus. Quisque tristique a sem tincidunt malesuada. Nulla vitae nulla ligula. In scelerisque velit in magna congue, semper fermentum neque aliquam.
        Sed sit amet erat vel lacus lacinia elementum. Pellentesque elementum sit amet turpis ut tristique. Proin laoreet elit porta, maximus lorem a, eleifend nisi. Phasellus ut maximus est, a ornare eros. Mauris tellus velit, iaculis tincidunt arcu
        quis, porta vulputate augue. Duis mattis, ante eu vehicula auctor, est lectus hendrerit augue, vel sollicitudin nisl odio quis libero. Quisque dui tortor, sodales sollicitudin semper vitae, hendrerit nec sem. Donec aliquet auctor felis, vel dictum
        ligula bibendum rutrum. In varius lacinia leo, ut tempor mi ornare vitae.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas congue lorem pellentesque scelerisque finibus. Quisque tristique a sem tincidunt malesuada. Nulla vitae nulla ligula. In scelerisque velit in magna congue, semper fermentum neque aliquam.
        Sed sit amet erat vel lacus lacinia elementum. Pellentesque elementum sit amet turpis ut tristique. Proin laoreet elit porta, maximus lorem a, eleifend nisi. Phasellus ut maximus est, a ornare eros. Mauris tellus velit, iaculis tincidunt arcu
        quis, porta vulputate augue. Duis mattis, ante eu vehicula auctor, est lectus hendrerit augue, vel sollicitudin nisl odio quis libero. Quisque dui tortor, sodales sollicitudin semper vitae, hendrerit nec sem. Donec aliquet auctor felis, vel dictum
        ligula bibendum rutrum. In varius lacinia leo, ut tempor mi ornare vitae.
      </p><p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas congue lorem pellentesque scelerisque finibus. Quisque tristique a sem tincidunt malesuada. Nulla vitae nulla ligula. In scelerisque velit in magna congue, semper fermentum neque aliquam.
        Sed sit amet erat vel lacus lacinia elementum. Pellentesque elementum sit amet turpis ut tristique. Proin laoreet elit porta, maximus lorem a, eleifend nisi. Phasellus ut maximus est, a ornare eros. Mauris tellus velit, iaculis tincidunt arcu
        quis, porta vulputate augue. Duis mattis, ante eu vehicula auctor, est lectus hendrerit augue, vel sollicitudin nisl odio quis libero. Quisque dui tortor, sodales sollicitudin semper vitae, hendrerit nec sem. Donec aliquet auctor felis, vel dictum
        ligula bibendum rutrum. In varius lacinia leo, ut tempor mi ornare vitae.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Consider using `display: grid` to create full page layouts.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.left-screen-container {
  height: 100vh;
}

.screen-specific-content {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr 7fr 1fr / auto;
}

.scrollable-content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.header {
  background-color: green;
}

.footer {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-screen-container">
    <div class="screen-specific-content">
        <div class="header">Header</div>
        <div class="scrollable-content">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas congue lorem pellentesque scelerisque finibus. Quisque tristique a sem tincidunt malesuada. Nulla vitae nulla ligula. In scelerisque velit in magna congue, semper fermentum neque aliquam.
                Sed sit amet erat vel lacus lacinia elementum. Pellentesque elementum sit amet turpis ut tristique. Proin laoreet elit porta, maximus lorem a, eleifend nisi. Phasellus ut maximus est, a ornare eros. Mauris tellus velit, iaculis tincidunt arcu
                quis, porta vulputate augue. Duis mattis, ante eu vehicula auctor, est lectus hendrerit augue, vel sollicitudin nisl odio quis libero. Quisque dui tortor, sodales sollicitudin semper vitae, hendrerit nec sem. Donec aliquet auctor felis, vel dictum
                ligula bibendum rutrum. In varius lacinia leo, ut tempor mi ornare vitae.
            </p>

            <p>
                Donec et ex nisl. Nulla vitae volutpat purus. Aenean interdum vitae libero quis dignissim. Phasellus consectetur nulla sit amet nibh pharetra pulvinar. Vivamus nisl erat, maximus sed quam vitae, bibendum mattis justo. Sed dapibus lacus ac orci luctus,
                sit amet euismod quam eleifend. Maecenas a nisl a nulla varius sagittis eget at urna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aenean id posuere turpis, eget laoreet felis. Nunc venenatis mi
                vitae sem bibendum, sed ultrices est malesuada. Donec mattis, elit a sodales placerat, leo nulla condimentum ex, id vestibulum dolor velit in enim. Mauris tempus commodo purus, nec rutrum nisi sollicitudin laoreet. Duis eu efficitur mi. Sed massa
                felis, tincidunt mollis efficitur sed, vulputate viverra nisl. Sed semper efficitur dolor ut efficitur.
            </p>

            <p>
                Curabitur et felis lobortis, dignissim quam ac, tempor nibh. Praesent at purus nunc. Duis egestas est non hendrerit aliquam. Donec tincidunt ante id ante condimentum molestie. Vivamus iaculis mi ut feugiat volutpat. Nullam non eleifend libero. Aliquam
                eleifend mollis turpis eget vestibulum. Sed sollicitudin leo at purus molestie scelerisque. Duis id metus nisl. Vestibulum sit amet suscipit nisl. Cras vulputate volutpat erat sed aliquam. Nulla commodo, sem non ullamcorper tristique, ex elit
                malesuada nisi, eget congue erat dui in felis.
            </p>

            <p>
                Suspendisse neque velit, tempor sed tempus vel, dictum in lacus. Vivamus eu viverra magna. Sed ut ligula rutrum, gravida lacus mattis, bibendum ante. Cras pretium eu augue sed vestibulum. Nulla mattis posuere nulla, id scelerisque tortor bibendum in.
                Nulla facilisi. Vivamus bibendum rutrum enim a euismod. Duis euismod tincidunt neque ut posuere. Quisque laoreet metus non purus molestie, at efficitur leo molestie. Maecenas id nibh vel massa viverra suscipit. Phasellus eleifend pretium laoreet.
                Proin dignissim pellentesque mattis.
            </p>

            <p>
                Etiam blandit velit ac leo accumsan, varius egestas augue egestas. Donec felis neque, volutpat ac odio quis, tempus vulputate sem. Pellentesque at suscipit lorem, vel consequat enim. Aenean tristique non ex non ultricies. Interdum et malesuada fames ac
                ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nunc eget fringilla ipsum, vel pretium justo. Morbi faucibus purus non feugiat sollicitudin. In efficitur imperdiet massa, eu convallis tellus. Curabitur commodo sem sit amet sodales dignissim. Nunc vel lacus quis
                eros rutrum porta. Nullam euismod nisi enim, ac auctor justo interdum sed. Integer condimentum egestas elit, quis pretium risus molestie in. Mauris iaculis ultricies viverra. Vivamus commodo sem magna, blandit euismod ipsum tristique ut. Class
                aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nulla fringilla efficitur risus, nec laoreet ipsum ultricies nec.
            </p>

            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas congue lorem pellentesque scelerisque finibus. Quisque tristique a sem tincidunt malesuada. Nulla vitae nulla ligula. In scelerisque velit in magna congue, semper fermentum neque aliquam.
                Sed sit amet erat vel lacus lacinia elementum. Pellentesque elementum sit amet turpis ut tristique. Proin laoreet elit porta, maximus lorem a, eleifend nisi. Phasellus ut maximus est, a ornare eros. Mauris tellus velit, iaculis tincidunt arcu
                quis, porta vulputate augue. Duis mattis, ante eu vehicula auctor, est lectus hendrerit augue, vel sollicitudin nisl odio quis libero. Quisque dui tortor, sodales sollicitudin semper vitae, hendrerit nec sem. Donec aliquet auctor felis, vel dictum
                ligula bibendum rutrum. In varius lacinia leo, ut tempor mi ornare vitae.
            </p>

            <p>
                Donec et ex nisl. Nulla vitae volutpat purus. Aenean interdum vitae libero quis dignissim. Phasellus consectetur nulla sit amet nibh pharetra pulvinar. Vivamus nisl erat, maximus sed quam vitae, bibendum mattis justo. Sed dapibus lacus ac orci luctus,
                sit amet euismod quam eleifend. Maecenas a nisl a nulla varius sagittis eget at urna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aenean id posuere turpis, eget laoreet felis. Nunc venenatis mi
                vitae sem bibendum, sed ultrices est malesuada. Donec mattis, elit a sodales placerat, leo nulla condimentum ex, id vestibulum dolor velit in enim. Mauris tempus commodo purus, nec rutrum nisi sollicitudin laoreet. Duis eu efficitur mi. Sed massa
                felis, tincidunt mollis efficitur sed, vulputate viverra nisl. Sed semper efficitur dolor ut efficitur.
            </p>

            <p>
                Curabitur et felis lobortis, dignissim quam ac, tempor nibh. Praesent at purus nunc. Duis egestas est non hendrerit aliquam. Donec tincidunt ante id ante condimentum molestie. Vivamus iaculis mi ut feugiat volutpat. Nullam non eleifend libero. Aliquam
                eleifend mollis turpis eget vestibulum. Sed sollicitudin leo at purus molestie scelerisque. Duis id metus nisl. Vestibulum sit amet suscipit nisl. Cras vulputate volutpat erat sed aliquam. Nulla commodo, sem non ullamcorper tristique, ex elit
                malesuada nisi, eget congue erat dui in felis.
            </p>

            <p>
                Suspendisse neque velit, tempor sed tempus vel, dictum in lacus. Vivamus eu viverra magna. Sed ut ligula rutrum, gravida lacus mattis, bibendum ante. Cras pretium eu augue sed vestibulum. Nulla mattis posuere nulla, id scelerisque tortor bibendum in.
                Nulla facilisi. Vivamus bibendum rutrum enim a euismod. Duis euismod tincidunt neque ut posuere. Quisque laoreet metus non purus molestie, at efficitur leo molestie. Maecenas id nibh vel massa viverra suscipit. Phasellus eleifend pretium laoreet.
                Proin dignissim pellentesque mattis.
            </p>

            <p>
                Etiam blandit velit ac leo accumsan, varius egestas augue egestas. Donec felis neque, volutpat ac odio quis, tempus vulputate sem. Pellentesque at suscipit lorem, vel consequat enim. Aenean tristique non ex non ultricies. Interdum et malesuada fames ac
                ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nunc eget fringilla ipsum, vel pretium justo. Morbi faucibus purus non feugiat sollicitudin. In efficitur imperdiet massa, eu convallis tellus. Curabitur commodo sem sit amet sodales dignissim. Nunc vel lacus quis
                eros rutrum porta. Nullam euismod nisi enim, ac auctor justo interdum sed. Integer condimentum egestas elit, quis pretium risus molestie in. Mauris iaculis ultricies viverra. Vivamus commodo sem magna, blandit euismod ipsum tristique ut. Class
                aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nulla fringilla efficitur risus, nec laoreet ipsum ultricies nec.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```